# How does the shortcut property sheet change icons instantly?

Tags: windows, winapi, shortcut, shortcut-file

When you change the icon in the shortcut property sheet, the shortcut icon changes instantly.

[image: Shortcut icon change]

When you run the Python script multiple times, you see the shortcut icons change each time to a random icon. However, when you comment out the `create_internet_shortcut` call in `main`, the icon of the manually written Internet shortcut "Bing.url" stops changing. There must be some additional processing that happens in the COM method after `SHChangeNotify`, which alone is not enough.

What do I need to do to make the Internet shortcut icon change when the URL file is written manually without using COM?

I have also tried calling `SHChangeNotify` 4 different times, but that didn't work. See the `update_all_icons` function and commented out call in `main`.

Install:

```
pip install pywin32
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from typing import Any, Tuple

import os
import random
import traceback
from pathlib import Path

from win32com import storagecon
from win32comext.shell import shell, shellcon
import win32gui
import pythoncom
import pywintypes

system_icon_file = r"%SystemRoot%\System32\shell32.dll"
system_icon_max_index = 326

desktop_path = Path(r"~\Desktop").expanduser()


def create_internet_shortcut(path: str, target: str = None) -> None:
    shortcut = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(
        shell.CLSID_InternetShortcut,
        None,
        pythoncom.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        shell.IID_IUniformResourceLocator
    )
    persist_file = shortcut.QueryInterface(pythoncom.IID_IPersistFile)
    persist_file.Load(path)

    if not isinstance(target, str):
        target = shortcut.GetURL()
        if target is None:
            target = "https://www.bing.com/"

    shortcut.SetURL(target)

    property_set_storage = shortcut.QueryInterface(pythoncom.IID_IPropertySetStorage)
    property_storage = property_set_storage.Open(shell.FMTID_Intshcut, storagecon.STGM_READWRITE)
    icon_file = system_icon_file
    icon_index = random.randint(0, system_icon_max_index)
    property_storage.WriteMultiple((shellcon.PID_IS_ICONFILE, shellcon.PID_IS_ICONINDEX), (icon_file, icon_index))
    property_storage.Commit(storagecon.STGC_DEFAULT)
    persist_file.Save(path, 0)


def create_link_shortcut(path: str, target: str = "%SystemDrive%") -> None:
    shortcut = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(
        shell.CLSID_ShellLink,
        None,
        pythoncom.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        shell.IID_IShellLink
    )
    persist_file = shortcut.QueryInterface(pythoncom.IID_IPersistFile)

    try:
        persist_file.Load(path)
    except pywintypes.com_error:
        traceback.print_exc()

    shortcut.SetPath(target)
    icon_file = system_icon_file
    icon_index = random.randint(0, system_icon_max_index)
    shortcut.SetIconLocation(icon_file, icon_index)
    persist_file.Save(path, 0)


def write_internet_shortcut(path: str, target: str = None) -> None:
    if not isinstance(target, str):
        target = "https://www.bing.com/"

    icon_file = system_icon_file
    icon_index = random.randint(0, system_icon_max_index)

    text = f"""[InternetShortcut]
URL={target}
IconFile={icon_file}
IconIndex={icon_index}"""

    with open(path, "w", encoding="utf8") as file:
        file.write(text)


def update_icon(path: str) -> None:
    shell.SHChangeNotify(shellcon.SHCNE_UPDATEITEM, shellcon.SHCNF_PATHW | shellcon.SHCNF_FLUSHNOWAIT, path, None)


def update_all_icons(path: str) -> None:
    result, info = shell.SHGetFileInfo(
        path,
        0,
        shellcon.SHGFI_ICON | shellcon.SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME | shellcon.SHGFI_TYPENAME
    )
    hIcon, iIcon, dwAttributes, displayName, typeName = info

    print("Info:", info)

    if iIcon > 0:
        shell.SHChangeNotify(shellcon.SHCNE_UPDATEIMAGE, shellcon.SHCNF_DWORD | shellcon.SHCNF_FLUSHNOWAIT, iIcon, None)
        shell.SHChangeNotify(shellcon.SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, shellcon.SHCNF_DWORD | shellcon.SHCNF_FLUSHNOWAIT, iIcon, None)

    shell.SHChangeNotify(shellcon.SHCNE_UPDATEITEM, shellcon.SHCNF_PATHW | shellcon.SHCNF_FLUSHNOWAIT, path, None)

    shell.SHChangeNotify(shellcon.SHCNE_UPDATEDIR, shellcon.SHCNF_PATHW | shellcon.SHCNF_FLUSHNOWAIT, str(desktop_path.resolve()), None)

    win32gui.DestroyIcon(hIcon)


def main(*args: Tuple[Any, ...]) -> None:
    create_internet_shortcut(str(desktop_path.joinpath("COM Internet.url").resolve()))
    create_link_shortcut(str(desktop_path.joinpath("COM link.lnk").resolve()))

    bing_file_path = str(desktop_path.joinpath("Bing.url").resolve())
    write_internet_shortcut(bing_file_path)
    update_icon(bing_file_path)
    # update_all_icons(bing_file_path)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-programming-on/1565926218/apds04.html

Comment: @HansPassant Are you saying that I should call `pythoncom.CoUninitialize()` at the end of or after `main`? Some of the demos in "win32comext\shell\demos\" don't bother to do that.

Comment: The code sample can indeed see that the icon of "Bing.url" changes randomly. So your question is to manually create a "Bing.url", then compile the code to change the icon? And why you don't want to use COM?